# Is it safe to deallocate resources in onStop()?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

***Hi All!***

I have an `Activity` which allocates quite lot of memory while it shows a visible layout. The UI heavily depends on this memory, however, there is no need to keep these allocations after the user traverses away from the `Activity` (usually by bringing another `Activity` to focus).

The `Activity` starts to allocate memory in `onResume()` and all is fine with that. It's the deallocation that confuses me a bit, though. As of now I release all memory in `onPause()` which also destroys the corresponding UI elements. Since the `Activity` is still visible while running `onPause()` the user will see the actual UI elements becoming destroyed. This is ugly and not what I want.

***So my question:***

1. Is it safe to release memory (destroy UI) in `onStop()` (according to documentation the `Activity` is not visible when `onStop()` is called)?
2. Is `onStop()` reliable?
3. Is `onStop()` guaranteed to be called every time when `onPause()` is called?

***Edit:***
I feel I must explain a bit more clearly what confuses me. According to [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> ...for those methods that are marked as being killable, after that
>   method returns the process hosting the activity may [be] killed by the
>   system at any time without another line of its code being executed...

The `onStop()` method is marked as "killable".

- Does the above mean (especially the "`after that method returns`" part) that the entire scope of `onStop()` is guaranteed to run, but once it returns nothing else is guaranteed any runtime (e.g. a spawned thread started in `onStop()`)?
- Or does it mean that `onStop()` might get interrupted even before it reaches the end of its scope (as of the `killed at any time` part)?
- Or does it mean something else that I - in my divine stupidity - don't see.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of allocations do you need to deallocate, and why can't you rely on normal GC operations?

Comment: It's actually a lot of different resources; results read from databases, assets used by heavy animations, in memory caches etc. The reason I don't want to keep these things in memory is that I have a few Activities which all behave like this. I'm afraid they will consume a significant amount of runtime memory (maybe all of it?), hence I wish to make sure - by enforcement - that everything not related to the focused activity is recycled. My problem is to find an appropriate and reliable stage in the Activity state machine where the recycling can be enforced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the activity sees to it that `onPause` should finish executing first before "destroying" the view, while `onStop` is a lifecycle stage that follows after the view is already in the background - meaning the activity is not visible anymore.

doing things inside `onPause` makes sure that the items you need to save are still intact before letting go of them - for example you need to save the text in your EditText, or the on/off position of RadioButtons, etc.

deallocation however doesn't need any of these things anymore, so it should be fine if you do it in your `onStop`

Comment: Great point! In the described use-case I'm not saving the state of any UI elements, I'm releasing previously allocated memory resources. The question that remains is if it's "guaranteed" that the `onStop()` is called every time the Activity is brought to the background.

Answer (score 0):

`onStop()` should be safe and reliable enogh for your purpose.

"Guaranteed" is relative in this case, given that your activity may be killed without any notification. But in that case your memory resources are released anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to ask you to back this up with references. I'm not sure a paying customer will accept my personal opinion (or yours) in any future discussions, actually they will most likely not accept any reference documentation either - they just want it to work. Your second point is fully valid though: the case where my app is brought down by the system is not necessarily a problem at the time being.

Comment: [Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) of the *Activity* tells me: "If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is stopped.", so *yes* *onStop()* is guaranteed to be called, **if** your task is not killed after *onPause()* which is possible on "pre-HONEYCOMB".

Comment: Oh, I think I see what your question actually is. And the answer is: As per the specs, *onStop()* will *not* be called as long as (part of) your activity is visible.

Answer (score 0):

1. it's as safe as anything else? Worse comes to worse your app will be killed with onDestroy. In mobile development, you basically have to assume that at any given moment your app could be killed.
2. It's been reliable for me in releasing media objects for a while now.
3. Not really guaranteed, as sometimes onDestroy is called depending on what's going on.

Comment: if you look closely at the activity lifecycle diagram (developer.android.com), the onStop method is the "in-between" state between onDestroy and onRestart. your activity can't just "jump" from onPause to onDestroy.

Comment: My problem is not the corner cases where the system brings down my app. It's more the default behaviour that needs to be fine tuned: I wish to release resources without the user seeing them being released (as my resources are tightly bound to UI, releasing resources are reflected in UI elements being removed).

Comment: if your app isn't responding properly to onStop or not freeing up resources quick enough for the system, onDestroy can be called any time. But yes - onStop is called first.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not safe as only onPause() is guaranted to be called.  onPause() means that yor activity loses focus - perfect place to give away not necessary resources

Comment: Unfortunately you might be correct in the essence of your statement :-) Whether onPause() is perfect to give back resources to the system is arguable; the Activity is still visible while `onPause()` runs, hence, recycling resources is - in my case - reflected in UI elements disappearing too early (the user can see them disappear) - this is what I wish to circumvent by recycling in a state where the activity has already hidden its UI.

Comment: Official Holy Scribe disagrees with you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle  onPause() is called when another activity of already on front and your lost focus.   There is also some additional weirdnes when screen lock comes  in play  - you arcivity is forced  to portait mode ( even if it has declaredn landscape )  and thus paused - started - paused ;) . You have to be careful there

Comment: Actually I would say that the Official Holy Scribe totally agrees with me: The activity is visible during onPause(). onPause() will even block any other activities from taking focus until it returns.